# Compare time offset Using Two Date objects

Tags: java, date, time

I have two date objects, Date1 and Date2. Date1 has a time and Date2 has a time, with an offset to UTC(only within the time, not the actual date itself):

`Date1: Thu Apr 13 20:41:46 CDT 2017`

`Date2: Thu Apr 13 15:41:46 CDT 2017`

I would like to take these two dates, extract their times, compare them, and then ensure they are correctly offset from my system time and UTC (this comparison also needs to take into account daylight savings).

(**Please note, there is not a way I can use java.time as the input. I understand it would be much easier but with our configurations I am stuck using java.util.Date as the input date**)

Here is my code to produce these date values, I just need a way to verify that the difference between the two is in fact the correct offset(without hardcoding the offset and having to change it at each daylight savings change):

```
public static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
public static final int MILLI_TO_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;

public static void main(String args[]) throws java.text.ParseException {
    Date date1 = nowInUTC();
    Date date2 = Date.from(Instant.now());
    System.out.println("date1: " + date1);
    System.out.println("date2: " + date2);

     /* Needs to be modified to contain the logic
      * I need to verify that the time given in date2 is the offset from date1
      * in respect to its timezone. You can ignore the CDT in date1*/
    if(true){
        System.out.println("You have the correct offset!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("you do not have the correct offset!");
    }
}

private static long toHours(long millis){
    return millis / MILLI_TO_HOUR;
}

private static Date nowInUTC() {
    try {
        Date date = new Date(new SimpleDateFormat(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT).parse(
                nowInUTCAsString()).getTime());
        return date;
    }
    catch(ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private static String nowInUTCAsString() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return sdf.format(new Date());
}
```

Comment: What you are asking, makes no sense (which may in fact help you). A `Date` object *does not have an offset to UTC*. It’s a common misunderstanding, probably greatly helped by the fact that its `toString` method picks up the JVM’s time zone setting and prints the date according to it. So with two `Date` objects in your program, none can have an offset within it, and both will print with the same offset, namely that of the JVM.

Comment: I notice you’re using `Instant.now()`, where `Instant` is a class of `java.time` (I assume). Are you saying your input is necessarily a `java.util.Date`, so that you may convert it to a `java.time` class and do your processing using the new classes? If so, this is what I would recommend.

Comment: Your `nowInUTC()` does something I can’t believe you want. Central Daylight Time is -5 hours offset from UTC. So when you ran your code at 15:41:46 CDT, UTC time was 20:41:46, and `nowInUTCAsString()` correctly produced a string like `2017-04-13T20:41:46.357` (just guessing at the decimals). Then `nowInUTC()` parses this string in *your local time zone*, producing a `Date` equal to 20:41:46 CDT, which is the same as 1:41:46 in the night UTC. Since the date always prints in the JVM’s time zone, you see it as `Thu Apr 13 20:41:46 CDT 2017` on your screen.

Comment: I understand that the Date object does not have an offset to UTC. I am forced to use the Date object (legacy code and database configuration issues.) I am forcing the x-hour(5 hour currently from central and UTC) offset with the nowInUTC() method. When I persist these values to the database, they will only take the value(it drops the CDT), and will look like the UTC date. I just want a method that I can find the current offset with UTC(which is 5 right now instead of 6 b/c of daylight savings) and be able to write a test to verify that I have the correct offset from UTC between the two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your comment with clarification for your interesting challenge. I understand that you do need to produce a date that is 5 hours ahead of time to compensate for the database taking the CDT time and understanding it as UTC. Actual offset depending on your computer’s time zone setting. I am assuming your database is running locally or at least is guaranteed to have the same time zone setting as your JVM — an assumption you should check.

Your code is basically correct in producing two dates with a difference equal to your computer’s offset from UTC, so you shouldn’t really be in need for a verification of that fact. I will add a nuance or two to this statement below.

First, how do you verify? Taking your word that you want to. Here’s my suggestion:

```
    LocalDateTime date1AsLdt = date1.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDateTime();
    LocalDateTime utc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    if (date1AsLdt.isEqual(utc)){
        System.out.println("You have the correct offset!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("you do not have the correct offset!");
    }
```

Even though I claim this is a correct way of checking, as correct as your way of producing `date1`, on my old computer it prints `you do not have the correct offset!` This is because the two times differ by up to a couple of hundred milliseconds. It’s not an error, it’s an inaccuracy in your code. It comes from your code reading the system clock twice, and depending on the time elapsing between the two readings, they may or may not agree. You read the clock first by creating `new Date()`, then again by `Instant.now()`. I recommend you read the clock just once and use the same reading for both dates.

Since you used `java.time.Instant` in your code, I have assumed you can use `java.time` internally as long as you end up producing a `java.util.Date`. `LocalDateTime` in my above code is in `java.time`too.

If this is OK, in your code there’s no need for the complication of converting to string and back. I suggest:

```
private static Date nowInUTC() {
    LocalDateTime utc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    return Date.from(utc.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

As I said, there are a number of assumptions in the above. If I’m wrong somewhere, please revert, and I shall be happy to take another look.

A final warning. There are a couple of hours around the change from DST to standard time each fall where clock times are ambiguous. Even when your program correctly produces UTC time (which is never ambiguous as UTC), your database will need to pick an interpretation of the time passed to it, and I can’t see it can have a way of picking the correct one.